# How to return columns with null values in a result map in mybatis

Tags: java, orm, mybatis, ibatis

```
<select id="keyEquipmentShiftAutomatedModelData" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultType="java.util.Map">
SELECT  ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2) Total
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
    </select>

Returns below result in sql

ID, Total
1   (null)
```

But when returned in Map result in myBatis returns {ID=1} where as Total is missing. How to get the column with null into the result set as well something like this {ID=1,Total=null} or something like this {ID=1,Total=""}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding

```
<settings>
<setting name="callSettersOnNulls" value="true"/>
</settings>
```

mybatis-config.xml fixes the issue if using mybatis 3.2 + version

Comment: you save my day, also 
    columns[i] = (value == null) ? "" : String.valueOf(value);

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it works, besides you need convert value

```
columns[i] = (value == null) ? "" : String.valueOf(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be fixed easily using `coalesce` in plain Sql:

```
COALESCE( SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2), '') as Total
```